# How to format clojure in emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am using CIDER with clojure in emacs, clojure mode is also enabled. But how to format the clojure code?  Or any other package could support the formatting of clojure code?

Comment: What do you mean by formatting?

Comment: Note that the method suggested in the linked duplicate works in most major modes, not just `clojure-mode`.